# My git uses someone else’s name and email

Tags: git

When I check the configuration information：

```
λ git config --list --show-origin

file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  user.name=Elijah-F
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  user.email=Zh...hen@163.com
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  pull.rebase=false
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  core.editor=vim
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  core.pager=diff-so-fancy | less --tabs=4 -RFX
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.ui=true
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  merge.tool=vimdiff
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff-highlight.oldnormal=red bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff-highlight.oldhighlight=red bold 52
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff-highlight.newnoral=green bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff-highlight.newhighlight=green bold 22
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.meta=11
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.frag=magenta bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.commit=yellow bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.old=red bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.new=green bold
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  color.diff.whitespace=red reverse
file:/home/fufuzhao/.gitconfig  commit.template=~/.gitmessage
file:.git/config    core.repositoryformatversion=0
file:.git/config    core.filemode=true
file:.git/config    core.bare=false
file:.git/config    core.logallrefupdates=true
file:.git/config    remote.origin.url=git@github.com:Elijah-F/dotfiles.git
file:.git/config    remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

I have checked many times and I feel that there is no error in my configuration.
But when I `git commit`, someone else’s name(bennyye) appears.

```
commit 8a15c8baeec40e35af64eb5d48396a9a3b2a40d8 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: bennyye <xxx@xxx.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 8 12:12:11 2021 +0800

    feat: .gitmessage
```

Actually, Bennyye is my colleague. But i am still very confused.Why does his name appear here？

Hope someone can help me, thank you！

Comment: Why are you posting peoples' email addresses here?  Please edit your question and give these people some privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_committing) for variables like:

- `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`
- `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`
- `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`
- `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`

They could have an impact on your final commit.

> The final creation of a Git commit object is usually done by git-commit-tree, which uses these environment variables as its primary source of information, falling back to configuration values only if these aren’t present.